# Which Java MVC frameworks integrate easily with StringTemplate?

Tags: java, frameworks, integration, template-engine, stringtemplate

It's hard to see how *StringTemplate* integrates easily (or not) with *popular* Java web MVC frameworks.

**Which Java MVC frameworks integrate easily with StringTemplate?**

A good answer:

- mentions **one solution** to integrate with a framework,
- includes a **link** to something useful and applicable, like:

  - a **tutorial**,
  - or **documentation**,
  - or a reference to **source code**:

    - **free**,
    - and **open source** or **public domain**.

**Readers/Voters**, please vote for a solution if you know it's true and great.

In the scope of this question, I am *not interested in any other templating engine than StringTemplate*.

Comment: Great question! Terrence is a genius, but he's still a bit academic. StringTemplate doesn't get the attention it deserves in large part because (afaik) no frameworks feature it.

Comment: It's incredible how out of the map StringTemplate is. It's already been 20 hours this question is up, and it's already buried - with 0 official integration solution. ...Looks like the ball is in our camp to help ST gain tractable presence in MVCs.

Comment: Hiya!  Yeah, ST will never be widely known w/o a big framework wrapped around it.  I came to loathe building sites, though, after making jguru server.  Nothing I can do to improve the situation, I'm afraid.  Very happy to hear people like it.  It's influential because I think it does the right thing but...  Because of ANTLR, ST is well known in code gen and translation circles.

Comment: I would think you could fit it into most frameworks.  I'm using it with slim3.  What I have done is instead of forwarding to JSP files from my Servlets, I render a template.  In slim3, this happens in Controller classes.  I've (so far) completely eliminated the JSP from my project.

Answer (score 11):

I've gotten StringTemplate to work with Spring.  Basically, all it took was a custom view.

But first, a disclaimer: This is an experimental hack.  I've never used this in production code, and it could use some improvement before that happens.  I think it is adequate to answer your question about how easily StringTemplate integrates with a Web MVC framework, however.

Reference: [Spring Web MVC documentation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html)

StringTemplateView.java:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;

public class StringTemplateView extends InternalResourceView {

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // Provides a Spring resource descriptor referring to the .st file
        Resource templateFile = getApplicationContext().getResource(getUrl());

        // Kind of redundant...
        StringTemplateGroup group = new StringTemplateGroup("group", templateFile.getFile().getParent());
        StringTemplate template = group.getInstanceOf(getBeanName());
        template.setAttributes(model);

        // Output to client
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print(template);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

And an example view resolver definition:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="myapp.web.view.StringTemplateView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/st-views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".st"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: +1. One thing I noticed with this code is that it does not work if your templates live in a subdirectory of /WEB-INF/st-views/. What I ended up doing was reconstructing the "prefix" using what effectively is getUrl().substring(0, getUrl().indexOf(getBeanName())); and using it in the getResource() call. Also I dropped the getParent() call when instantiating StringTemplateGroup().

Answer (score 2):

A quick search led me to this [demonstration of using StringTemplate for a Spring view](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-3266).

Answer (score 1):

The open source Java WEB framework [JPublish](http://code.google.com/p/jpublish/), works very well with ST. By following the link above, you'll find there the following:

- a JPublish framework user guide
- a practical demo (downloadable from Google code ~5.7MB) showing you how to use ST from JPublish. You'll realize how easy it is.

Have fun,

Answer (score 1):

There is a not bad implementation of StringTemplate as a view for Spring MVC that also supports SiteMesh integration.

https://github.com/tomcz/spring-stringtemplate/

There is an example implementation of a webapp using ST as the view technology within this project (including the sitemesh integration). It is not worth repeating it here, so the pointer to it directly is:

https://github.com/tomcz/spring-stringtemplate/tree/master/src/test/webapp/WEB-INF

The author has also provided support for encoding/escaping output for XSS prevention. This support exists for HTML, CSS, XML, JS and URLs.

If you're a Maven user, the project is available on central

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.watchitlater</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-stringtemplate</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A certain Harry Karamidas [shared](http://www.stringtemplate.org/share/list), in December 2008, a **Struts** adapter on ST's official site. [Direct link](http://www.stringtemplate.org/share/1229347891527/st_struts_adapter_with_demo.0.2.zip) to the zip file.